# Get nth number from a string

Tags: php, string, memory, explode

I have a very large file with only single line.  It contains about 2.6 million of numbers.  The file is about 15 mb.

My goal is to find the nth number in this single line string.

I tried to read the file into a string (remember it is single line file).  Then I exploded the strings into an array which I ran out of memory.  (Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)

Am I doing it right?  Or is there another easier way to find the nth value in a very large string?

```
$file = file_get_contents ('a.txt', true);
$array = explode(" ", $file, -1);
echo $array[$nth];
```

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, in PHP.

Comment: We need to know more about your file. When you say 2.6 million numbers, you're obviously not talking about 2.6 million *digits*, or the file would be 2.6 mb, not 15mb. So show us an example of what you're actually working with.

Comment: Since OP's exploding the string, we're talking about space-separated numbers. I guess.

Comment: You can always analyze the file in smaller segments, say one MB at a time.

Comment: The file is like this:  122 322 3222 2111 852 211 -233 358 0 12 ......., space delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter variable; read the file using `fopen` and loop it in a while with `feof` and `fgets` (with the desired buffer size); within the loop, check how many spaces are present in the bit you just read (I'm assuming your entries are separated by spaces, it could be commas or whatever); finally increment the counter and go on until you reach the part you want (after a `n` number of spaces, you have the `[n+1]th` entry you are looking for).

I include some tested (with a 16 MB file) proof-of-concept code. I don't know if there are better ways to do it; this is the only one that came to my mind and it works. `memory_get_usage` reports a memory usage of ~8 kb.

```
<?php

$counter;
$nth = 49959;
$handle = @fopen('numbers.txt', 'r'); // File containing numbers from 1 to 2130829, size ~16 MB.

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 128)) !== false) {
        $spaces = substr_count($buffer, ' ');

        if ($counter + $spaces > $nth) {
            $numbers = explode(' ', $buffer);
            $key = $nth - $counter;
            echo $numbers[$key]; // print '49959'
            exit;   
        }
        else {
            $counter += $spaces;
        }
    }

    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  As indicated above, the numbers are all different size, example 0, 122, -233, etc.  They are space delimited. How do I use fgets to read one number (not digit) a time?

Comment: You cannot, but that doesn't matter because you're just looping until you find your number. I wrote a proof-of-concept code, and tested it. I included it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Entropid.  I think this works!  But I am also wondering if I put these numbers in a mysql table with ID, Number as the only two columns.  So I can look it up by ID every time I need to look something up.  will that be faster than do the fgets every time?

Comment: Yes, it'd be better. It depends if you have already an infrastructure with MySQL set up or not.